# How do I force a view that is shared between areas to use the area layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 site with areas and I have some System views that I want to share between the areas. Each area has its own separate layout. When I access a System view (by explicitly specifying `area = ""`), it uses the layout page from the main _ViewStart.cshtml file. The problem is, I want to use the layout of the Area instead.

I have tried removing the Layout declaration from the main _ViewStart.cshtml file and even removing the _ViewStart.cshtml file altogether, but all that does is make my System view render with no layout at all.

I also ran across [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) that explains you can put complex logic in your _ViewStart.cshtml file to do this. I tried, but had problems when trying to render partial views on the same page (that are area specific). It would seem that I need to "reset" the area parameter within _ViewStart.cshtml, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

How do I make a main view (from `/Views/` folder) take on the layout of the area that called the view? Keep in mind, I don't want to hard code it to the layout of a specific area.

The obvious thing to do would be to make a copy of the System views and their controller in each area, but I am trying to avoid having duplicated files (DRY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using a customized _ViewStart.cshtml that sets the area back to where it was via ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens. In my case, the area is determined by the TenantType enum in the ApplicationContext (a set of values stored in HttpContext.Current.Items), so getting at it wasn't too difficult.

```
var appContext = new ApplicationContext();
var area = appContext.CurrentTenant.TenantType.ToString();
this.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = area;
Layout = "~/Areas/" + area + "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

So basically, we are calling a shared controller named SystemController which simply returns View(). That directs it to look for a controller in the common /Views/ControllerName folder, which is where my shared view is.

When it calls _ViewStart.cshtml, it sets the Area back to the current area (which in my case is determined by looking up the domain name in the database). This allows the Area _Layout.cshtml page to use the partial views that are stored in the Area/Shared folder.

Finally, we set the layout page explicitly to the current area's layout.